# Изменение содержимого страницы ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: c#, .net

В winforms приложении используется библиотека Dotnetbrowser для отображения некоторой страницы, когда она недоступна выходит страница с ошибкой Err_connection_refused. Можно ли как то изменить содержимое этой страницы или отловить событие с этой ошибкой?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для того чтобы изменить эту страницу есть несколько способов. Один из них который у меня заработал :
Нужно добавить код в событие FinishLoadingFrameEvent. Это событие принимает в себя объект класса FinishLoadingEventsArgs. У этого объекта есть поле ValidatedURL. Мы его сравниваем с получившимся результатом, если он равен ему то загружаем свою страницу или ещё что то делаем.
If(FinishLoadingEventsArgs.ValidatedURL == "chrome-error://chromewebdata/")
Browser.LoadHTML(ваш  html) ;